# How to Find All SQL Server database back list in my system?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, backup

My SQL Server 2008 R2 system has different database backups on different drives like `C:`, `D:`, `E:`

Now I would like to see all database backups listed in SQL Server 2008 R2.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Your question is hard to understand ! Do you want a list of backups that happened on your server ?

Comment: For Eg I received  Sql Server DB Backup from my client .Then I save for Colon D: then I restore  my Sql Server ,After One week back received Another DB Backup then I save Colon C: then I restore SQl Server Different :and same scenario  five times done. Now I want to see all DB back up list using any query.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of this is that you have received multiple backups from a client, saved them to different locations (C:, D:, E:) and restored them. Now you would like to write a query to see all of those backups.

If that's really what you're trying to do, this sounds more like a file system task than a SQL query. If all the backup files have the same extension (such as .bak) then you could use either [command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423935/windows-command-line-search-for-exact-extension-with-dir) or [Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18871063/powershell-file-extension-while-searching) to scan through your folders and find all files with that extension.

If instead you are trying to get a list of all the databases you have restored, you can find a list of all databases on your SQL Server instance with the following query:

`SELECT * FROM sys.databases;`

Comment: `If instead you are trying to get a list of all the databases you have restored ... ` I dont see how `SELECT * FROM sys.databases` will give a list of databases that are restored. You have to check `msdb.dbo.restorehistory`. What you have mentioned will just give what databases are currently on the server instance.

Comment: It will give you a list of all databases on the instance, which will include the ones that were restored.

Comment: Agreed, but how are you going to differentiate what databases are restored ? `sys.databases` only lists names of databases. If you want to find out what databases got restored then `msdb.dbo.restorehistory` is the right place. I have my own sandbox where no databases were restored, so `sys.databases` is misleading in that context.

Answer (score 1):

> For Eg I received Sql Server DB Backup from my client .Then I save for Colon D: then I restore my Sql Server ,After One week back received Another DB Backup then I save Colon C: then I restore SQl Server Different :and same scenario five times done. **Now I want to see all DB back up list using any query.**

Below is the script that will give you a comphrensive list of backups and restores along with file locations, who and when backups and restores were done, etc

Study the script first and understand what it is doing !!

```
DECLARE @DBNAME VARCHAR(100)

SET @DBNAME = NULL  -- Default NULL(All Databses)
                    -- 'database_name' (for specific database)

SELECT 'BackUp Name' = BS.NAME
    ,'User Name' = BS.user_name
    ,'Start Date' = BS.backup_start_date
    ,'Finish Date' = BS.backup_finish_date
    ,'Backup Type' = CASE 
        WHEN BS.type = 'D'
            THEN 'FULL Backup'
        WHEN BS.type = 'L'
            THEN 'Transaction Log Backup'
        WHEN BS.type = 'I'
            THEN 'Differential Backup'
        END
    ,'Backup Size MB' = floor(((BS.backup_size / 1024) / 1024))
    ,'DbName' = BS.database_name
    ,'Server Name' = BS.server_name
    ,MF.physical_device_name
    ,'IS Ever Restored' = CASE 
        WHEN BS.backup_set_id IN (
                SELECT backup_set_id
                FROM msdb.dbo.restorehistory
                )
            THEN 'Yes'
        ELSE 'No'
        END
    ,'Destination Db' = isnull(RH.destination_database_name, 'Yet Not Restored From This BackUpSet')
    ,'Restore Path' = isnull(min(RF.destination_phys_name), 'Yet Not Restored From This BackUpSet')
    ,'restore Type' = isnull(CASE 
            WHEN RH.restore_type = 'D'
                THEN 'Database'
            WHEN RH.restore_type = 'F'
                THEN 'File'
            WHEN RH.restore_type = 'G'
                THEN 'Filegroup'
            WHEN RH.restore_type = 'I'
                THEN 'Differential'
            WHEN RH.restore_type = 'L'
                THEN 'Log'
            WHEN RH.restore_type = 'V'
                THEN 'Verifyonly'
            WHEN RH.restore_type = 'R'
                THEN 'Revert'
            ELSE RH.restore_type
            END, 'Yet Not')
    ,Rh.restore_date
    ,'Restore By' = isnull(RH.user_name, 'No One')
    ,'Time Taken' = cast(datediff(ss, BS.backup_start_date, BS.backup_finish_date) / 3600 AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' Hours, ' + cast(datediff(ss, BS.backup_start_date, BS.backup_finish_date) / 60 AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' Minutes, ' + cast(datediff(ss, BS.backup_start_date, BS.backup_finish_date) % 60 AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' Seconds'
FROM msdb..backupset BS
INNER JOIN msdb..backupmediafamily MF ON BS.media_set_id = MF.media_set_id
LEFT JOIN msdb..restorehistory RH ON BS.backup_set_id = RH.backup_set_id
LEFT JOIN msdb..restorefile RF ON RF.restore_history_id = Rh.restore_history_id
WHERE BS.database_name = isnull(@DBNAME, BS.database_name)
GROUP BY BS.NAME
    ,BS.user_name
    ,BS.backup_start_date
    ,BS.backup_finish_date
    ,BS.TYPE
    ,BS.backup_size
    ,BS.database_name
    ,BS.server_name
    ,MF.physical_device_name
    ,BS.backup_set_id
    ,RH.destination_database_name
    ,RH.restore_type
    ,Rh.restore_date
    ,RH.user_name
```